# jQuery dataTables row count filtering across pages

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a huge datatable with a lot of pages, and I have to count the rows that have a specific value.

How can I count across all pages?

Examples ...

Html:

```
<tr class="item_line  odd" role="row">
  <td>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down hover-blue" onclick="Toogle(this)"></i>
    <label class="right"><input name="Items[%INDEX_ITEM%].Item" class="input-light input-xs width50" style="width: 50px !important;" onkeypress="return onlyInt(event);" type="text" value="10"></label>
  </td>
  <td><span>MM0123455</span></td>
  <td>COMPOSTO 10KG</td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
// ....
if ($(":input[name='Items[%INDEX_ITEM%].Item'][value='" + item +"']").length == 0) {
    // ....
} else {
    // ....
}
// ....
```

Fiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/na406ffv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can create the datatable into a variable and use it to filter rows into all pages at same time.

```
var tableItems = $("#tester").DataTable(
{
    lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, 250, -1], [25, 50, 100, 250, "All"]], 
    pageLength: 3,
    pagingType: "full_numbers", 
    scrollY: "400px", 
    scrollCollapse: true
});
```

And get the total count:

```
$("#count10").click(function(){ alert(tableItems.$(":input[name='Items[%INDEX_ITEM%].Item'][value='10']").length) });
```

Fiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/na406ffv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**[`table.rows().data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data())** gives you complete data set assigned to your `datatable`. Using this, you can just loop through each row and count for required data.

```
var count = 0;
$("#count10").click(function() {
  count = 0;
  var data = table
             .rows()
             .data();
  $(data).each(function(k, v) {
      var elem = $(v[0]).find(":input[name='Items[%INDEX_ITEM%].Item'][value='10']");
      elem.length ? count++ : 0;
  })
  alert(count);
});

$("#count20").click(function() {
  count = 0;
  var data = table
             .rows()
             .data();
  $(data).each(function(k, v) {
      var elem = $(v[0]).find(":input[name='Items[%INDEX_ITEM%].Item'][value='20']");
      elem.length ? count++ : 0;
  })
  alert(count);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/na406ffv/3/)**

To generalize, you can write a common `click event` for you buttons and write more efficient code as below:

button html would be

```
<button id="count10" data-count="10" class="count">Count 10</button>
<button id="count20" data-count="20" class="count">Count 20</button>
```

**Click event**

```
var count = 0;
$(".count").click(function() {
    count = 0;
    var filt = $(this).attr("data-count");
    var data = table
               .rows()
               .data();
    $(data).each(function(k, v) {
       var elem = $(v[0]).find(":input[name='Items[%INDEX_ITEM%].Item'][value='" + filt + "']");
       elem.length ? count++ : 0;
    })
    alert(count);
});
```

**[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/na406ffv/4/)**

---

> **Please note that this might not be an ultimate solution. You can also think of some other ways to filter your data once you get all data from `table.rows().data()`.**